# Spring Security - ant matcher permit all not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a problem with antMatchers. This is not working as I expected.
I try to permit for All endpoint /tokens/**, but when this endpoint is called, my filters are called too(JwtTokenVerifier)

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/tokens/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .cors()
            .and()
            .addFilter(new JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(), this.jwtProperties, objectMapper))
            .addFilterAfter(new JwtTokenVerifier(this.jwtProperties), JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

Every time when I try to access for example /tokens/refresh-access-token JwtTokenVerifier is called.

```
@PostMapping("/tokens/refresh-access-token")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public Map<String,String> refreshAccessToken(@RequestBody String refreshToken)
```

Token verifier:

```
public class JwtTokenVerifier extends OncePerRequestFilter {

private final JwtProperties jwtProperties;

public JwtTokenVerifier(JwtProperties jwtProperties) {
    this.jwtProperties = jwtProperties;
}

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                HttpServletResponse response,
                                FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible, you could try and exclude the URL completely from Spring Security processing, by overriding the WebSecurity method. I don't know, though, if you want to completely ignore the FilterChain for that path.

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/tokens/**");
}
```